# Reading a file in C, theory questions

Tags: c

I was given an assignment in C language about reading and writing in a file.
I have read different codes on different websites and also their explanations. but there is one question that remained unanswered! Following is the general code I found on different sites:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void main()
{
   FILE *fp;
   int c;
   fp = fopen("E:\\maham work\\CAA\\TENLINES.TXT","r");
   c = getc(fp) ;
    while (c!= EOF)
     {
       putchar(c);
       c = getc(fp);
     }
    fclose(fp);
 }
```

My questions are simple and stright.

in line `c = getc(fp) ;` what is that C receives?? address? character? ASCII Code?? what?

and

```
while (c!= EOF)
{
   putchar(c);
   c = getc(fp);
}
```

here how is c able to read the file character by character?? there is no increment operator... does the pointer "fp" helps in reading the code??

lastly, why is `putchar(c);` used in printing ? why not use `printf("%C", c);` ?

Comment: Did you read the documentation?

Comment: Are you one of these people that unpacks a piece of equipment and toss the manual into the bin. Then wonder why you cannot get it to work?

Comment: I was reading randomly on web. n no.... I read the entire manual :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getc()` returns the integer value of the byte at the current position in the file handle, then advances that position by one byte.

`putchar()` is simpler than `printf`.

Answer (score 0):

1 minute googling got me this.

1. C++ reference
2. tutorial points
3. wikipedia

---

Quoting reference documentation ([C++ here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/getc/), but probably very similar in C).

```
int getc ( FILE * stream );
```

> Get character from stream Returns the character currently pointed by the internal file position indicator of the specified stream. The internal file position indicator is then advanced to the next character.
>
> If the stream is at the end-of-file when called, the function returns EOF and sets the end-of-file indicator for the stream (feof).
>
> If a read error occurs, the function returns EOF and sets the error indicator for the stream (ferror).
>
> getc and fgetc are equivalent, except that getc may be implemented as a macro in some libraries. See getchar for a similar function that reads directly from stdin.

Further reading gives us:

> On success, the character read is returned (promoted to an `int` value).
>
> The return type is `int` to accommodate for the special value `EOF`, which indicates failure: If the position indicator was at the `end-of-file`, the function returns `EOF` and sets the eof indicator (feof) of stream.
>   If some other reading error happens, the function also returns `EOF`, but sets its error indicator (ferror) instead.

---

[Here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_getc.htm) we read

> This function returns the character read as an `unsigned char` cast to an `int` or `EOF` on end of file or error.

---

And on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_file_input/output)

> Reads a `byte`/`wchar_t` from a file stream